# Javascript onload event to resize image help

Tags: javascript

This might be a simple one for you guys, im learning Javascript and have hit a problem. I am trying to have the script resize a particular image on the page when onload is called like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function resizeSampleImage()
 {
  document.getElementById("sampleImage").style.height = (document.body.clientWidth) * 0.2;
 }

    </script>
```

...

```
<body onload = "resizeSampleImage();" >
```

...

```
<a href="http://www.buildingpeople.uk.com" target="_blank"> <img id="sampleImage" src="Images/BP snip.jpg" alt="BuildingPeople.uk.com" /> </a>
```

apologies, forgot to mention that is doesn't work! after loading the page in multiple browsers the image stays it native size and the error consoles say they fail to parsing value for height. Declaration dropped.

I have tried lots of different ways but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: you should probably mention what the problem is!

Comment: Thanks. Good point! I have added this now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though I haven't figure out the problem. But the following code snippet works for me (Tested in Chrome 8.0 and IE9.0Beta).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function resizeSampleImage()
            {
                document.getElementById("sampleImage").style.height = (document.body.clientWidth) * 0.5;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="resizeSampleImage();">
        <img id="sampleImage" src="http://news.mydrivers.com/Img/20101217/S03405153.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange, when i copy and paste the above code and swap the image to my own it works!

Comment: Ok when i remove the doctype declaration at the top of the page it works!

Comment: That is because you have entered Quirks modes. This causes browsers to emulate the bugs of ancient browsers. One of these bugs is treating an integer as a pixel length in CSS. They also become highly inconsistent. **Quirks mode is undesirable**

Answer (score 0):

`(document.body.clientWidth) * 0.2` will give you an integer. The CSS `height` property accepts a [length](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length).

Add some units.

Comment: doesn't (document.body.clientWidth) return an length ? i am them just trying to calculate 20% of this.

Comment: No, it returns an integer. If it did return a length, multiplying it by 0.2 would output `NaN` (which also isn't a length)

Comment: changing the statement to document.getElementById("sampleImage").style.height = 500px; still doesnt work is this also wrong ? thanks for you time by the way I appreciate the help.

Comment: In JavaScript, you don't have to quote a Number, but you do have to quote a String.

Answer (score 0):

There is a live example at http://jsbin.com/uyihe4

You can see the zoom effect when loading. I have only changed the

```
document.getElementById("sampleImage").style.height
```

to

```
document.getElementById("sampleImage").height
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that the images may not be ready when you apply the styles to them.

Use this function instead (note it takes a DOM object):

```
var imgLoader = function(domImg) {
  var imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.onload = function() 
  {
    // apply styles
    domImg.style.height = "100px";
  }
  imgObj.src = domImg.src;
}
```